# Pass a form and an array through a single ajax

Tags: ajax, forms, spring-boot

I'm trying to pass a serialized form and an array through a single ajax call. I'm getting an error everytime I submit. I want to receive both in my controller and I have no idea how to do it. This is my code based on other tutorials I found online but it doesn't work.

ajax call:

```
var o = Array.prototype.slice.call(document.getElementsByName("client_beneficiary[]")).map(e => e.value);
$.ajax({
     url: "/SaveProductApplication",
     type: "post",
     data: {
          $("#product_form").serialize(),
          beneficiary_list: o
     },
     success: function() {}
});
```

controller:

```
@RequestMapping(value= "/SaveProductApplication", method=RequestMethod.POST)
public @ResponseBody boolean save(ProductApplication productApplication, @RequestParam(value="beneficiary_list[]") String[] beneficiary_list) {

    for (String arrElement : beneficiary_list) {
        System.out.println("Item: " + arrElement);
    }
}
```

hoping you could help me. thank you!